# localStorage JS как правильно использовать

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Всем привет! Недавно начал изучать JS, при создании "ToDo" формы столкнулся с тем, что после обновления страницы пропадают все добавленные дела. Узнал про localStorage, вроде получилось правильно вписать в свой код, но при обновлении все равно пропадает весь список. Помогите добрым советом)))

```
window.onload = function(){

  var todoList = [];

  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
    var d = document.getElementById('in').value;

    var temp = {};
    temp.todo = d;
    temp.check = false;
    var i = todoList.length;
    todoList[i] = temp;
    console.log(todoList);
    out();
    localStorage.setItem('todo', JSON.stringify(todoList) );
  }

  function out(){
    var out = '';
    for (var key in todoList){
        if (todoList[key].check == true){
            out += '<input type="checkbox" checked>';
        }
        else {
            out += '<input type="checkbox">';
        }
        out += todoList[key].todo + '<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = out;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function(){

  var todoList = [];
  var stored = localStorage.getItem('todo');
  if (stored)
    todoList = JSON.parse(stored);
  out();

  document.getElementById('add').onclick = function(){
    ...
  }

  function out(){
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Код сработал)))

Comment: @Moran Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: жду когда таймер  просчитает 5 минут)